# Noty jquery / Prototype.js / Internet Explorer 8 Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I am building a webapp where i use this wonderful jquery notification plugin: http://needim.github.com/noty/ 
Everything works pretty good in every browser except Internet Explorer 8. It seems for some strange reason that it conflicts with the prototype.js which is a very handy framework that i also need for lightbox 2. Is there any way i can make those two play nice together? 
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: are you using jQuery.noConflict() to avoid conflict with protottypejs?

Comment: The error message i get from IE8 is "Object doesn't support this property or method". As soon as i remove the prototype.js from the code, internet explorer works. but i do really need both.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using two different js libraries that do most of the same things. Why not use a jQuery lightbox plugin and leave out prototype, or replace your jQuery usage with prototype?

Comment: Well, the good news is that jquery.noconflict worked. But lightbox will not load unless noty is executed once. Then lightbox works fine. Strange, but it is logical due to the fact that i am using two js libs. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$.noConflict();` to make jQuery work together with prototype.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

But the better solution would be to use only one framework.
Multiple frameworks only to add multiple plugins are usualy a very bad idea.

Comment: noConflict worked for IE8 but unfortunately lightbox still has issues with loading, while noty works fine. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Maybe the Version of prototype an lightbox are not matching.